# What is a minimum deflection rating for a spring?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm looking at trying to use some springs to isolate percussive noise* traveling between closed rooms from a walking treadmill in an office environment. I found the following website (below) for springs, but they list "Minimum deflection is 0.75"". What is this measurement? Does this mean I need to load the springs so they deflect to 0.75" for them to be of any use?

https://www.globalindustrial.com/p/unhoused-simple-spring-mount-2-long-2-wide-yellow

*Meaning, every time your foot hits the deck of the treadmill, there's a little thud sound.

Comment: I think it says the spring needs a preload in order to have the optimum performance under vibratory loading conditions as so explained in its product information.

Answer (score 1):

The static deflection is given because its a measure of the vibration isolation properties. More specifically the deflection of a spring $\delta L$ is

$$\delta L = \frac{F}{K} \tag{eq.1}$$

When you substitute for F, the weight of the structure that is supported then $F = mg$. So the above equation becomes:

$$\delta L = \frac{mg}{K} \tag{eq.2}$$

However, the natural frequency of the system is $\omega_n = \sqrt{\frac{K}{m}}$, therefore eq.2 can be rewritten as:

$$\delta L = \frac{g}{\omega_n^2} \Rightarrow  \omega_n^2= \frac{g}{\delta L} 
 \tag{eq.3}$$

So the static deflection is a measure of the natural frequency. **Large deflections are indicative of small natural frequencies**.

Thus the ratio ($r= \frac{\omega}{\omega_n}$) of the excitation frequency ($\omega$) to the natural frequency ($\omega_n$) tends to be larger as $\delta L$ increases.

The transmissibility ratio indicates the magnitude of the displacement that is transmitted from the treadmill to the ground. As you can see, the transmissibility ratio is less that one as r increases over $\sqrt{2}$.

[image]

**Figure :  Transmissibility ratio source: [Xicong Zou](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Transmissibility-curve-for-different-damping-ratio_fig2_269319894))**

Therefore, because lower values of the transmissibility ratio provide better isolation vibration, $\Rightarrow$ larger values of r are desired, $\Rightarrow$ larger values of spring deflection are desired.

Comment: I am lost. How the (larger r) explains the recommended preload?

Comment: I agree, this is a nice explanation of why one would want to have larger deflections, but it doesn't answer the question of what the minimum deflection is. Also, looking at the original paper, this appears to apply to an entirely different mechanism from the coil spring referenced in the question.

Comment: @maxthecat The minimum deflection is given so that the optimal spring is selected (lighter objects would require less stiff springs) in order to have the optimal vibration isolation properties (at least for the frequency that the spring where designed). Regarding the transmissibility ratio graph: the TR concept is universal for all systems that can be model as a single degree of freedom system. So although I took the image from a paper with a different mechanism is still applicable. My reference was only acknowledgment of the work of the author).